# Pandas- binning number of minutes in various datetime ranges

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime, binning

I am looking for an efficient way to process the following data in pandas.

I have a dataframe containing several hundred thousand start and end timestamps:

```
data_df
                      start_ts                     end_ts
0    2019-06-10 12:00:00+00:00  2019-06-10 22:30:00+00:00
1    2019-06-11 12:00:00+00:00  2019-06-11 13:30:00+00:00
2    2019-06-11 14:00:00+00:00  2019-06-11 19:00:00+00:00
3    2019-06-14 12:00:00+00:00  2019-06-14 18:30:00+00:00
4    2019-06-10 12:00:00+00:00  2019-06-10 21:30:00+00:00
5    2019-06-11 12:00:00+00:00  2019-06-11 18:30:00+00:00
...
```

I also have a set of labeled time bins (`tp1`-`tp10`).  There are 10 bins each day, but the times of those bins can change from day to do (e.g.- `tp1` might be from 00:00 to 01:30 on one day, but then 00:00 to 01:45 on another day).  Each data set to be processed has 7 days, with 10 time periods per day, so the set of ranges is of size 70, and looks like:

```
labeled_bins_df
                   start_range                  end_range  label
0    2019-06-10 00:00:00+00:00  2019-06-10 04:30:00+00:00    tp1
1    2019-06-10 04:30:00+00:00  2019-06-10 09:45:00+00:00    tp2
2    2019-06-10 09:45:00+00:00  2019-06-10 12:30:00+00:00    tp3
...
```

What I would like is a table with the original `data_df` data, but with additional columns, `tp1` through `tp10`, with the number of minutes each row:

```
timed_bins
                      start_ts                     end_ts    tp1    tp2    tp3    tp4 ...
0    2019-06-10 12:00:00+00:00  2019-06-10 22:30:00+00:00      0      0     30    120 ...
1    2019-06-11 12:00:00+00:00  2019-06-11 13:30:00+00:00      0     45     45      0 ...
```

I am currently doing this naively, looping over my rows, and searching for the bins each data row is in, and as you can imagine, this is quite slow.  Is there any pandas-fu that can be performed to do this kind of binning on datetime ranges?

EDIT:  A thought, which might help think in a new direction.  If I were to convert all of my timestamps (both in my data, and in my labeled bins) into unix timestamps (seconds since Jan 1, 1970), then it would be a matter of binning/summing based on integer ranges rather than dates.  This would then yield the number of seconds in each bin, simply divide by 60, and I get my minutes in each bin.  This takes away all concerns about date boundaries, etc.

EDIT 2:  As requested, here is a set of simplified sample data, using three different time bins.  I specifically made one of the data samples (the second row) span 2 days.  Additionally, there is a `result_df` that shows the expected output.

```
data_samples = [
    {'start_ts': '2019-06-10T12:00:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-10T22:30:00+0000'},
    {'start_ts': '2019-06-10T22:00:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-11T05:30:00+0000'},
    {'start_ts': '2019-06-10T10:00:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-10T14:15:00+0000'},
    {'start_ts': '2019-06-12T08:07:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-12T18:22:00+0000'},
    {'start_ts': '2019-06-11T14:03:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-11T15:30:00+0000'},
    {'start_ts': '2019-06-11T02:33:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-11T10:31:00+0000'}
]

data_set = [{
    'start_ts': datetime.datetime.strptime(x['start_ts'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'),
    'end_ts': datetime.datetime.strptime(x['end_ts'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')} for x in data_samples]

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_set)[['start_ts', 'end_ts']]

time_bin_samples = [
    {'start_ts': '2019-06-10T00:00:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-10T08:15:00+0000', 'label': 't1'},
    {'start_ts': '2019-06-10T08:15:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-10T18:00:00+0000', 'label': 't2'},
    {'start_ts': '2019-06-10T18:00:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-11T00:00:00+0000', 'label': 't3'},

    {'start_ts': '2019-06-11T00:00:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-11T09:00:00+0000', 'label': 't1'},
    {'start_ts': '2019-06-11T09:00:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-11T19:15:00+0000', 'label': 't2'},
    {'start_ts': '2019-06-11T19:15:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-12T00:00:00+0000', 'label': 't3'},

    {'start_ts': '2019-06-12T00:00:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-12T10:30:00+0000', 'label': 't1'},
    {'start_ts': '2019-06-12T10:30:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-12T12:00:00+0000', 'label': 't2'},
    {'start_ts': '2019-06-12T12:00:00+0000', 'end_ts': '2019-06-13T00:00:00+0000', 'label': 't3'},
]

time_bin_set = [{
    'start_ts': datetime.datetime.strptime(x['start_ts'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'),
    'end_ts': datetime.datetime.strptime(x['end_ts'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'),
    'label': x['label']} for x in time_bin_samples
]

time_bin_df = pd.DataFrame(time_bin_set)[['start_ts', 'end_ts', 'label']]

result_set = [
    {'t1': 0, 't2': 360, 't3': 270},
    {'t1': 330, 't2': 0, 't3': 120},
    {'t1': 0, 't2': 255, 't3': 0},
    {'t1': 143, 't2': 90, 't3': 382},
    {'t1': 0, 't2': 87, 't3': 0},
    {'t1': 387, 't2': 91, 't3': 0}
]

result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_set)
```

Comment: do start_ts and end_ts ever span more than a single date?

Comment: Yes, they could span from one day to another.

Comment: That really complicates things, since `tp_i` varies by day you don't know beforehand whether you'd need tp1 from the first day or tp1 from the second day. Now the question is, are any of these spans large enough that they overlap the same `tp_i` span on different days (which have different limits)? What happens then?

Comment: I doubt there would ever be `tp1` from day 1 and `tp1` from day 2 for a single row (though I guess its not impossible).  That being said, I dont care how much comes from each day.. I am simply trying to sum up the total amount of time spent in `tp1`  So if there was a long sample, that contained say 30 minutes of time in `tp1` from day 1, and 15 minutes of time in `tp1` from day 2, I need the total `tp1` time of 45 minutes.

Comment: To clarify- by 'needing the total time in `tp1`', I mean `tp_i` for all `i` (not just tp_1).

Comment: Could you provide a minimal data set for a few days to help us testing?

Comment: Sure, let me put one together.  I'll tack it on to the original question.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - I added the requested sample/simplified dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that iterating the rows of a dataframe is not efficient.

Here I would try to identify the first and last bin per row in `data_df` by using `merge_asof`.

Then I would build a list of sub-dataframes by iterating once the dataframe values in order to add all the bins corresponding to a row and would concat that list.

From there it it enough to compute the time interval per bin and use `pivot_table` to get the expected result.

Code could be:

```
# store the index as a column to make sure to keep it
data_df = data_df.rename_axis('ix').reset_index().sort_values(
    ['end_ts', 'start_ts'])
time_bin_df = time_bin_df.rename_axis('ix').reset_index().sort_values(
    ['end_ts', 'start_ts'])

# identify first and last bin per row
first = pd.merge_asof(data_df, time_bin_df, left_on='start_ts',
                      right_on='end_ts', suffixes=('', '_first'),
                      direction='forward').values
last = pd.merge_asof(data_df, time_bin_df, left_on='end_ts', right_on='start_ts',
                     suffixes=('', '_ bin')).values

# build a list of bin dataframes (one per row in data_df)
data = []
for i, val in enumerate(first):
    elt = time_bin_df[(time_bin_df['ix']>=val[3])
                      &(time_bin_df['ix']<=last[i][3])].copy()
    # compute the begin and end of the intersection of the period and the bin
    elt.loc[elt['start_ts']<val[1], 'start_ts'] = val[1]
    elt.loc[elt['end_ts']>val[2], 'end_ts'] = val[2]
    elt['ix_data'] = val[0]
    data.append(elt)

# concat everything
tmp = pd.concat(data)

# compute durations in minutes
tmp['duration'] = (tmp['end_ts'] - tmp['start_ts']).dt.total_seconds() / 60

# pivot to get the expected result
result_df = tmp.pivot_table('duration', 'ix_data', 'label', 'sum', fill_value=0
                            ).rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

It can take some time because there is still one lengthy operation to build the list of dataframes, but other operations should be vectorized.